# How to comment on Jenkins build failed results

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a big testing team and there are so many tests fails on Jenkins almost everyday. Is there any way to comment on failed tests/build to see which failed test was taken care by any tester? This way its easy to track if anyone working on it instead of going and asking them in person.

Comment: I too wish there was such a feature.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but if you go the page for a particular build, you can click "Edit build information" and add comments for the build. Any comments you enter will show up at the top of the build page as well as in the Build History section on the job page.

Also we use the junit plugin and that does allow you to add a description on any level of the test results (package, class, method). If you're using the junit plugin, look for the "Add Description" link toward the upper right hand of the page.

Comment: It's not really comments, just a description for a build. But it's the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Claim plugin for Jenkins https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Claim+plugin. There you can set responsible person for the failing build and explain why it is failing.

I hope that works in your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to see a quick overview of failed builds and status, simplest solution would be the one TheEllis suggested.

You can also use Emojis to mark some status.
[image]